# Who do I get a PHP form to return to the same URL with ?search_string appended?

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a PHP page index.php but this applies to HTML as well. On this page I need a simple search form. The test entered in the form needs to reload to index.php?searchstring

E.g. Enter text '123' into the form and hit submit, the page reloads as 'index.php?123'

Surely there is an easy way to do this, but I can't find it!

Comment: There actually isn't, but you can do `index.php?q=123` by using a `GET` form with `<input name="q" />`.

Comment: Thanks, but that's what I want to avoid as my search can be for a number of different things and the page is already coded to search for them.

Comment: I think seeing your html is a good idea :)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use a GET form instead of POST.

```
<form method="get">
    <input type="search" name="q" value="<?= $_GET['q']; ?>">
</form>
```

Comment: That returns index.php?q=123 whereas I need it to return index.php?123

Comment: @user1222302 But why? I'm struggling to think of a reason to do that which can't be solved by using a normal query string.

Answer (score 0):

If you use **URL Rewriting** you could acheive something like this:

```
www.example/index/123
```

or

```
www.example/index.php/123
```

But I find these methods redundant. I don't understand way you can not just do:

```
index.php?search=123
```

Note: Maybe look into `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` as this might be your solution.

In your PHP, all you have to do is:

```
<?php

    $search = $_GET['search'];

?>
```

You dont have to rewrite any code. Because somehow your script is accessing the GET variables in the URL. Just set the old variables equal to the new.

```
$oldVariable = $search;
```

Comment: The script in use allows for multiple variables to be searched for. I don't want to re-write the script, just have the form return whatever is searched for after a '?' in the URL. $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] still get ?q= in the URL or if I remove the "q" then I just get a ? with nothing after it